# S3Content Length Error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a file to S3 and am running into an odd issue. If I don't set the ContentLength, then the file upload runs fine. And I ca still set the MD5. But if I do try to set the content-length (which is a best practice for this) then I get a timeout error on the write presumably becuase the size I sending S3 and the actual size are different (so it thinks 's it's still waiting on content.)

Here is my code.

```
private PutObjectResult storeFile(String key, InputStream content) {

    PutObjectResult result = null;
    if (content != null) {
        PutObjectRequest request;
        try {
            ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
            metaData.setContentLength(IOUtils.toByteArray(content).length);
            byte[] resultByte = DigestUtils.md5(content);
            String streamMD5 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(resultByte));
            metaData.setContentMD5(streamMD5);
            request = new PutObjectRequest(S3_BUCKET,
                    key, content, metaData);
            result = client.putObject(request);
        } catch (AmazonS3Exception e){
            LOG.error("Error writing to S3", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Error writing to S3", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("IO exception creating the MD5", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating an MD5", e);
        }



    }
    return result;
}
```

I have 2 sets of code calling this. One is taking data from an outputstream and converting it to an InputStream

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = engine.render(template.getContent(), data);
    InputStream content = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
    doc.setContent(content);
```

The other is taking a Base64 encoded String, un-encoding it to a byte[], and then turning that into an InputStream.

```
            String content = template.getFileContent();
        byte[] contentBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(content);
        PutObjectResult result = this.storeFile(key,
                new ByteArrayInputStream(contentBytes));
```

The first method working (where we start with an OutputStream, but the one where we start with the Base64 encoded string doesn't.

Error I get is

```
AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 018D75871D4E4F56, AWS Error Code: RequestTimeout, AWS Error Message: Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed., S3 Extended Request ID: 04guESsxeumTi3Bh0/SfL2q8rNwDq6PObGq12imLwVZxkZs4X+8outdlYAiHr47+
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're reading `content` three (!) times. Two times here:

```
metaData.setContentLength(IOUtils.toByteArray(content).length);
byte[] resultByte = DigestUtils.md5(content);
```

The first line fetches everything from the stream and sets its length correctly with `setContentLength()`. The second line gets an empty stream. This line gets an empty stream again:

```
result = client.putObject(request);
```

Read it just once into byte array, close the stream, and manipulate the array.